# Does it hold that the $p$-adic completion of the integers equals the completion of the localization in $p$?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

maybe this is a stupid question, but I could not solve it even for the ordinary integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Furthermore, I don't have to much knowledge on algebraic number theory and ramifications.

Let $K$ be a number field and $v$ a discrete valuation on it. Now let $\mathcal{O}_{K,v}$ be the localization at $v$, with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}_v = \mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_{K,v}$. Is it true that $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{K,v}} \cong \varprojlim_n \; \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^n$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are profinite completions and the residue fields are isomorphic.

That is

$$\mathcal{O}_{K,v}/\mathfrak{p}^n\cong \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}^n$$

where each $\mathfrak{p}$ is within the ambient ring, so that the inverse limits are isomorphic, since the profinite completion of $\mathcal{O}_K$ WRT $\mathfrak{p}$ is given over the inverse system of progressive quotients by powers of $\mathfrak{p}$ as is true for the localizations.

In particular, the inverse systems are

> $$1\;\longleftarrow \;\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}\;\longleftarrow \;\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^2\longleftarrow \;\ldots\longleftarrow\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^n\longleftarrow \;\ldots$$
>   $$1\longleftarrow \;\mathcal{O}_{K,v}/\mathfrak{p}_v\;\longleftarrow \;\mathcal{O}_{K,v}/\mathfrak{p}_v^2\longleftarrow\ldots\longleftarrow\mathcal{O}_{K,v}/\mathfrak{p}_v^n\longleftarrow\ldots$$

and there is a componentwise isomorphism which is compatible with the transition maps (each arrow is reduction modulo the next lowest prime power), hence is an isomorphism of inverse systems.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'm missing something very trivial, but why does $$\mathcal{O}_{K,v}/\mathfrak{p}^n\cong \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}^n$$ hold?

Comment: Use the third isomorphism theorem iteratively by noting

$$(R/I)\bigg /(J/I)\cong R/J$$

and the fact that $\mathfrak{p}^{k}/\mathfrak{p}^{k+1}\cong\Bbb F_{N(\mathfrak{p})}$ for $k\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Ok, clearly I'm missing something, but doesn't $\mathbb{Z}_{( p )}/(p) \cong \mathbb{Q} $, because $\mathbb{Z}_{ (p ) } = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} ; v(x) \geq 0 \}$?

Comment: $p\equiv 0\mod p$ and $\Bbb Q$ has characteristic $0$. You're not localizing more, you're quotienting. Every number in $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ is being sent to its equivalence class $\mod p$, which means $a/b\in\Bbb Q$ with $p\not | b$ is sent to $[a][b]^{-1}\mod p$ where $[b]^{-1}$ is the inverse class to the integer, $[b]\mod p$, which exists since $(b,p)=1$.

Comment: Sure, but isn't the quotient field of a valuation ring over  $\mathbb{Q}$ equals $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: What do you mean? $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ is not a $\Bbb Q$-module (you cannot act on it by things with denominator divisible by $p$).

Comment: I mean if $v$ is a valuation on $K$, then $R_v = \{ x \in K ; v(x) \geq 0  \}$ has quotient field equals to $K$, right?

Comment: No, it has **fraction** field equal to $K$. A quotient field is of the form $R/M$ for some maximal ideal $M\subseteq R$, a fraction field is the set of quotients of elements of an integral domain, $R$.

Comment: Ops! sure, you're right. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal in the commutative ring $A$,
then the natural map from the $\mathfrak m$-adic completion of $A$ to 
the $\mathfrak m$-adic completion of the localization $A_{\mathfrak m}$ is an isomorphism, the reason being that at each finite stage, the morphism
$$A/\mathfrak m^n \to A_{\mathfrak m}/\mathfrak m^n A_{\mathfrak m}$$
is an isomorphism, because any element of $A\setminus \mathfrak m$ has invertible
image in $A/\mathfrak m$, and hence in $A/\mathfrak m^n$.

This last assertion is where we use that $\mathfrak m$ is maximal, and the statement
is not true if $\mathfrak m$ is not maximal.